# How was the duration of loop decided in The Endless?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-endless

The movie [*The Endless*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3986820/) had some very short time loops like the one in the tent and some long loops like Hal and the team.

So what is the explanation of their different duration of time loops?

Despite being in the same area why the loop duration was different for each group? On what basis the loop duration was decided?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but judging from the description on Wikipedia these loops seem to be part of some kind of torture/punishment that is applied by others as their entertainment. Why would these loops always be the same length then? And why would there be a need to explain the uneven lengths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for the time duration of each loop is entirely arbitrary. The parameters for size and duration of creation of a loop are unknown to both the viewer and the characters within the movie. The only thing we know as the viewer is that there is a separate cosmic entity that creates and controls the loops. It's pretty heavily implied that each loop is created purely for the entity's enjoyment, but we never figure out the true extent of the entities abilities, powers, size, or even how many loops exist.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be clearly answered in the film itself, but Justin Benson, one of the makers of the film, has answered it in an interview:

> **Benson**: You know the Gandalf staff looking things, the rock formations they talk about in the beginning? Those actually form the borders of the different loops. So when you cross into one past that, you come to a different loop each time. If you want to be really specific, the radius or diameter of the circles they form, as it gets bigger, the loop gets longer and as they get smaller, the loops get smaller. So when you see the five second tent, you see them all around it. It’s about a 20 foot diameter. That’s why the guy has such a short loop.

[‘The Endless’ Directors Justin Benson and Aaron Moorhead on Toxic Nostalgia and Time Loops [Interview] (page 3)](https://www.slashfilm.com/the-endless-interview/3/)

Of course, this doesn't explain everything: Can the markers be moved or destroyed?  Can a time loop be made longer by moving its markers farther out?  But it does establish a direct relationship between the two.